# Rails 4 Single form-two actions -preview and assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which has  two buttons

- One will assign the form, i mean create an entry in corresponding table after validation and redirect to another page
- Second will give a preview of the values submitted on the form.For the preview screen we need some calculations so that an action to be called from controller and respective page will be loaded.
  This page should seen on the same form if i clicked preview before assigning the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i would address this is to change your `new` action so that it takes the same params as the create action, and makes the object but doesn't save them.  This means that if you call the new action with the params it will reload the form with the built but not saved objects' data displayed in it.

The two buttons will need to change the form's `action` attribute so that it submits to the create or the new action as appropriate.

This is a general answer, as your question is quite general!